# Declined parsing ansible inventory

Tags: ansible, gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner, ansible-inventory

Hello I have some problems with Ansible. I am trying to run playbook using Gitlab CI but I get this error.

```
Using /ansible/ansible.cfg as config file
setting up inventory plugins
host_list declined parsing /ansible/inventory as it did not pass its verify_file() method
script declined parsing /ansible/inventory as it did not pass its verify_file() method
auto declined parsing /ansible/inventory as it did not pass its verify_file() method
Parsed /ansible/inventory inventory source with ini plugin
Loading collection ansible.windows from /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/ansible_collections/ansible/windows
Loading collection community.windows from /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/ansible_collections/community/windows
ERROR! couldn't resolve module/action 'win_git'. This often indicates a misspelling, missing collection, or incorrect module path
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eftFC.png)

Answer (score 0):

Ignore the first part regarding inventories.  That is just Ansible's trying to parse the inventory files in different ways.

For the last bit, it looks like you need to install this package: https://github.com/tivrobo/ansible-win_git

And put that module where Ansible can find it.